# Can you map typescript types to other types generically?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can return one of 2 different types. I want to specify the return type using a generic parameter, but I don't want to specify the actual return type. Instead, I want to specify `true` or `false` and have the function map that to the actual return type. Is this possible in TypeScript?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-hcvywritDSoXKAA)

```js
// function that gets some data that can be parsed as a string[] or as a number
const getData = () => {
    return JSON.parse('...');
};

// function that parses the data as a string[]
const fooTrue = () => {
    return getData() as string[];
};

// function that parses the data as a number
const fooFalse = () => {
    return getData() as number;
};

// the types for x and y work out, but I had to make 2 functions for foo (fooTrue and fooFalse)
const x = fooTrue(); // string[]
const y = fooFalse(); // number

// single function for foo
const foo = (flag: boolean) => {
    if(flag) {
        return getData() as string[];
    }
    return getData() as number;
}

// the types for xx and yy don't work out :(
const xx = foo(true); // number | string[]
const yy = foo(false); // number | string[]

// generic version, but you have to specify the actual return type
const fooGeneric = <T extends unknown>() => {
    return getData() as T;
}

// the types for xxx and yyy work out, but I had to specify string[] and number instead of true/false
const xxx = fooGeneric<string[]>(); // string[]
const yyy = fooGeneric<number>(); // number

// function that converts true/false types to string[]/number types, respectively
const functionIWant = <???>(???) => {
    ???
}

const xxxx = functionIWant<true>(); // should return a string[]
const yyyy = functionIWant<false>(); // should return a number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional type should work for you.

```
const functionIWant = <T extends boolean>(): T extends true ? string[] : number => {};
```

Comment: Thanks! For reference, [Conditional Types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript supports function [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). So something like this is possible:

```
function foo(flag: true): string[];
function foo(flag: false): number;
function foo(flag: boolean) {
    if(flag) {
        return getData() as string[];
    }
    return getData() as number;
}
```

Note: Arrow functions cannot be overloaded